# Kubernetes: How to Identify What Setting Causes A ClusterRole To Have Elevated Privilege

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac

I have a CICD `ClusterRole` resource which I like to limit access to only viewing (and perhaps updates) on GKE `v1.23`.

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: cluster-auth
  name: github-actions-ops
  namespace: default
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs:
      - "get"
```

This is bound to my serviceaccount as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: cluster-auth
  name: github-actions-ops
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: github-actions-ops
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: github-actions-ops
```

For some reason it allows me to change this resource such that I could add an extra `verb` (`- delete`) through my corresponding serviceaccount.

`can-i` subcommand on resources also results in `yes` when create/patch verb was tested.

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                                                   CLUSTER                                                AUTHINFO                 NAMESPACE
*         DEV-NAME                                               DEV-NAME                                               github-actions-ops-dev   
          PRD-NAME                                               PRD-NAME                                               github-actions-ops-prd
$ kubectl auth can-i patch deploy --as=system:serviceaccount:default:github-actions-ops --namespace default
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i create service --namespace default
yes
```

My understanding is that the `get` verb should restrict this behavior. How could I find what is causing this clusterrole resource to have more privilege?

Comment: Very strange... please, try checking which user you are running the kubectl command with.
Take a look at the .kube/config file, in the section that matches the "DEV-NAME" context.
It could be that you are checking with your username, which has elevated privileges on the cluster.

As for the kubectl command, try it like this:
`kubectl auth can-i <verb> <resource> --as=system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<serviceaccountname> [-n <namespace>]`

Comment: They seem to be alright. I wrote the settings myself by setting up ca.crt and token from secret generated during the creation of svc account. I tested revoking my gcloud auth, trying garbage tokens for confirmation, but I found no evidence that points my usual account was used.

Comment: It produces a yes, I will add these flags to question

Comment: Ok, to make the final test I created the same resources that you indicated in the "question" (+ the Service Account of course).

This is the result:
`kubectl auth can-i patch deploy --as=system:serviceaccount:default:github-actions-ops --namespace default
no`

Try checking that the clusterRole has no other privileges by running the command:
`kubectl -n default describe clusterrole.rbac github-actions-ops`

Comment: The comments don’t show the code very well... The result of the kubectl command is "NO", so it works for me with your files.

Comment: It produces the expected result (no other permissions except: `*.*  []  []  [get]`). Unfortunately, this is occuring to all service-accounts... I will change the question when I make time.